# Is there a comprehensive API or JSON/XML list with public/bank holidays worldwide?

Tags: api, calendar

As I´m building a web app that includes a calendar as one of it´s features and that can be used all over the world, as a connivence to users I´d like them to easily include their local holidays. Ideally I´d like to just store their country and pull a list from an API.

Ideal would be a API that on request gives back the bank holidays for a given year and country.

What I´ve found so far:

### **[wikipedia.org - Holiday country list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_holidays_by_country)**

- Nice list, probably a nightmare to scrape and complile into a computer readable list for the next years.

---

### **[bank-holidays.com](http://www.bank-holidays.com)**

- Commercial Vendor, seems to have everything, although pricing to the
  updated feed is unclear. Did not yet respond to my email. Publicly
  available pricepoint is 250EUR, but per download/update.

---

### **Google calendar lists**

e.g. en.german%23holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com
Seems nice, not always fully up to date and not sure if it´s ok to use that information.

Countries supported by google:
Australian, Austrian, Brazilian, Cambodian, Canadian, China, Christian, Danish, Dutch, Finnish, French, German, Greek, Hong Kong (C), Hong Kong, Indian, Indonesian, Iranian, Irish, Islamic, Italian, Japanese, Jewish, Malaysian, Mexican, New Zealand, Norwegian, Philippines, Polish, Portuguese, Russian, Singapore, South Africa, South Korean, Spain, Swedish, Taiwan, Thai, UK, US & Vietnamese Holidays

Comment: [Nager.Date](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.Date) used the informations of wikipedia. It is also a API available.

Answer (score 36):

[Enrico Service](http://kayaposoft.com/enrico/) looks promising, at least for little site without high reliability demand

Answer (score 7):

WebCal.fi has about 30 countries' holidays and other stuff available in XML, JSON and a few other formats, more countries coming. Free or at least cheap.

http://www.webcal.fi/en-US/other_file_formats.php

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that it's your own website you're suggesting, to minimize the risk of being flagged as spam.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Just wanted to keep the message brief and to the point. I didn't realize this might not be appropriate. Will delete the answer if requested.

Comment: Great site... Yet, i could not find bank/public holidays? Is there a way to display the ones that are public holidays - where most offices are closed?

Comment: On the page linked, select Calendar > Holidays (they're not called Bank holidays in most countries, and even in the UK not all holidays are actually Bank holidays altough the difference is semantic). To see a different country, select one above. The UI will also change language, but the site should still be semi-understandable.

Comment: @AapoPuskala Moi! You should probably clearly state the affiliation in the body of the post tough (comments may get periodically cleared off dom't rely on info in comments), read last paragraph [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). I think you fit within the category just make it into the post please. **PS**: I know Aapo personally so i would give him the benefit of doubt based on that, so others do judging.

Comment: Would like to use this but no JSONP support for Cross domain requests... shame.

Comment: Siegemos, this is the first time I hear about JSONP. After some reading I think I understand what it is about. If you'd like support for it, please contact me directly as I have some questions about it. I'd rather not fill this question about JSONP as it is not really related to the original question.

Comment: For things I do, JSON is trivial to use (iOS / MacOS X directly translates JSON to an array or dictionary). JSONP requires finding some library or writing code; it is not 100% compatible with JSON, and it's binary which makes it harder to read/debug.

Answer (score 3):

Potentially: http://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/holiday-api.html

```
$100 / year
Ability to get lists of holidays for one country, selected at time of ordering.
100,000 requests
1 Country
```

*(not sure what to think about pricing, looks pricey to me)*

Comment: timeanddate.com is too expensive! I'm only dealing with two states, so its cheaper to type them into the program myself and update it each year.

Comment: @CrazyTim You can try https://holidayapi.com/ at $5 per month, if you pay yearly you get 2 months free. They don't have a java client lib so I wrote one myself - https://github.com/agogs/java-holiday-api/